# Python scraping via xml prints empty brackets

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to extract just a few characters from a website via lxml, to tree, then xpath. I've tried using google chrome to obtain the correct xpath yet it prints empty brackets.

```
    #imports
    from lxml import html
    import requests

    #get magicseaweed Scripps report
    msScrippsPage = requests.get("""http://magicseaweed.com/Scripps-Pier-
    La-Jolla-Surf-Report/296/.html""")

    #make tree from site
    msScrippsTree = html.fromstring(msScrippsPage.content)

    #get wave size
    msScrippsWave = msScrippsTree.xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/text()""")

    print 'ms SCripps: ', msScrippsWave
```

The output to terminal is 'msScripps: [ ]'

Comment: msScrippsPage holds a 404. Check your URL?

Comment: @Will Did you copy the triple quotes too? I don't get a 404 when i copy/paste what I typed above without triple quotes.

Comment: Ah. Mine now prints: ms SCripps:  ['    1-2', '   ']

Comment: @Will what did you modify to get the 1-2 to appear?

Comment: Genuinely nothing. Well, only the line with the URL. Your triple quotes are including a newline character in it.

Comment: @Will interesting, what did you modify about that line?

Comment: See @Oleksandr Dashkov answer below

Comment: Your xpath is very brittle  and will break with the slightest change to the html

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Any tips to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use line break in your url. When you use one line your xpath work.

```
msScrippsPage = requests.get("""http://magicseaweed.com/Scripps-Pier-La-Jolla-Surf-Report/296/.html""")
print msScrippsPage.content
['    0.4-0.6', '   ']
########################################
url = """http://magicseaweed.com/Scripps-Pier-
La-Jolla-Surf-Report/296/.html"""
print url
'http://magicseaweed.com/Scripps-Pier-\n    La-Jolla-Surf-Report/296/.html'
```

Edit: Add full example

```
from lxml import html
import requests

msScrippsPage = requests.get("""http://magicseaweed.com/Scripps-Pier-La-Jolla-Surf-Report/296/.html""")
msScrippsTree = html.fromstring(msScrippsPage.content)
msScrippsWave = msScrippsTree.xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/text()""")
print 'ms SCripps: ', msScrippsWave
```

Comment: Now it prints 'ms Scripps:  [<Element li at 0x1033b94c8>]

Comment: I think that you forgot text() in the end of your xpath. Could you just copy/paste example(I added to the answer)?

Comment: If this is a good solution you should accept it so Oleksandr gets reputation score :)